# How to iterate over an array of strings and returns matching word

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm testing text search on PostgreSQL and I would like to search for multiple terms based on a custom dictionnary

I have :

```
CREATE TABLE events (name text NOT NULL, description text NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO events VALUES
  ('Phaeleh Live','Phaeleh, one of the UK''s most vital production talents and a key innovator')
 ,('Radar 009','Radar Radio''s weekly parties re-launch for 2018 with some of their biggest line-ups yet.')
 ,('14anger','Collector of techno classics, admirer of futuristic sequencing, he weaves these together for an eternal timed prophecy rave');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW unique_lexeme AS
SELECT word FROM ts_stat(
$TS_STAT$
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', events.name) || to_tsvector('english', events.description) as document
  FROM events
$TS_STAT$);
```

Then for the query :

```
WITH word_similarity AS (
  SELECT word
  FROM unique_lexeme
  WHERE similarity(word, 'par') > 0.1 
  ORDER BY word <-> 'par'
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT events_name,
       events_description
       FROM (
       SELECT events.name AS events_name,
         events.description AS events_description,
         to_tsvector('simple', events.name) || to_tsvector('english', events.description) as document
  FROM events) events_search, word_similarity
WHERE events_search.document @@ to_tsquery('english', word_similarity.word || ':*')
ORDER BY ts_rank(events_search.document, to_tsquery('english', word_similarity.word || ':*')) DESC;
```

But how could I make `word_similarity` able to return a list of matching term I will search after?
For example if I provide `['wee','vit']` I will get `['week','vital']`.

Can I do it with a recursive CTE? or do I need to write a for each loop in PL/pgSQL?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fbc98/7)